# Phabricator Storage Upgrade Not Completing

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, mysql

I am attempting to upgrade two Phabricator servers with glaring PHP5 vulnerabilities. The first server went without an issue but the second one does not seem to be able to complete the storage upgrade using the command:

```
./bin/sudo storage upgrade
```

I have tried using the username and password switches with a user I was sure could connect to mysql as well as --force but I always get the below output every time after the command is run:

```
Applying patch "phabricator:20170528.maniphestdupes.php" to host "localhost"...
[2017-10-26 20:36:14] EXCEPTION: (Exception) No configured storage engine can store this file. See "Configuring File Storage" in the documentation for information on configuring storage engines. at [<phabricator>/src/applications/files/storage/PhabricatorFile.php:314]
arcanist(head=master, ref.master=0989343a4e0c), phabricator(head=master, ref.master=beaf0ad9a636), phutil(head=master, ref.master=95c065963998)
  #0 PhabricatorFile::buildFromFileData(string, array) called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/files/storage/PhabricatorFile.php:428]
  #1 PhabricatorFile::newFromFileData(string, array) called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/files/builtin/PhabricatorFilesComposeAvatarBuiltinFile.php:174]
  #2 PhabricatorFilesComposeAvatarBuiltinFile::getUserProfileImageFile(string) called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/people/cache/PhabricatorUserProfileImageCacheType.php:54]
  #3 PhabricatorUserProfileImageCacheType::newValueForUsers(string, array) called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/people/query/PhabricatorPeopleQuery.php:618]
  #4 PhabricatorPeopleQuery::fillUserCaches(array) called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/people/query/PhabricatorPeopleQuery.php:448]
  #5 PhabricatorPeopleQuery::rebuildAvailabilityCache(array) called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/people/query/PhabricatorPeopleQuery.php:208]
  #6 PhabricatorPeopleQuery::didFilterPage(array) called at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/query/policy/PhabricatorPolicyAwareQuery.php:273]
  #7 PhabricatorPolicyAwareQuery::execute() called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/phid/type/PhabricatorPHIDType.php:91]
  #8 PhabricatorPHIDType::loadObjects(PhabricatorObjectQuery, array) called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/phid/query/PhabricatorObjectQuery.php:153]
  #9 PhabricatorObjectQuery::loadObjectsByPHID(array, array) called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/phid/query/PhabricatorObjectQuery.php:73]
  #10 PhabricatorPolicyAwareQuery::execute() called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/phid/query/PhabricatorHandleQuery.php:46]
  #11 PhabricatorHandleQuery::loadPage() called at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/query/policy/PhabricatorPolicyAwareQuery.php:236]
  #12 PhabricatorPolicyAwareQuery::execute() called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/phid/handle/pool/PhabricatorHandlePool.php:73]
  #13 PhabricatorHandlePool::loadPHIDs(array) called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/phid/handle/pool/PhabricatorHandleList.php:44]
  #14 PhabricatorHandleList::loadHandles() called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/phid/handle/pool/PhabricatorHandleList.php:49]
  #15 PhabricatorHandleList::getHandle(string) called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/phid/handle/pool/PhabricatorHandleList.php:130]
  #16 PhabricatorHandleList::current()
  #17 iterator_to_array(PhabricatorHandleList) called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/transactions/query/PhabricatorApplicationTransactionQuery.php:144]
  #18 PhabricatorApplicationTransactionQuery::willFilterPage(array) called at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/query/policy/PhabricatorPolicyAwareQuery.php:247]
  #19 PhabricatorPolicyAwareQuery::execute() called at [<phabricator>/resources/sql/autopatches/20170528.maniphestdupes.php:26]
  #20 require_once(string) called at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/storage/management/PhabricatorStorageManagementAPI.php:285]
  #21 PhabricatorStorageManagementAPI::applyPatchPHP(string) called at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/storage/management/PhabricatorStorageManagementAPI.php:241]
  #22 PhabricatorStorageManagementAPI::applyPatch(PhabricatorStoragePatch) called at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/storage/management/workflow/PhabricatorStorageManagementWorkflow.php:1103]
  #23 PhabricatorStorageManagementWorkflow::doUpgradeSchemata(array, NULL, boolean, boolean) called at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/storage/management/workflow/PhabricatorStorageManagementWorkflow.php:849]
  #24 PhabricatorStorageManagementWorkflow::upgradeSchemata(array, NULL, boolean, boolean) called at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/storage/management/workflow/PhabricatorStorageManagementUpgradeWorkflow.php:78]
  #25 PhabricatorStorageManagementUpgradeWorkflow::didExecute(PhutilArgumentParser) called at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/storage/management/workflow/PhabricatorStorageManagementWorkflow.php:107]
  #26 PhabricatorStorageManagementWorkflow::execute(PhutilArgumentParser) called at [<phutil>/src/parser/argument/PhutilArgumentParser.php:441]
  #27 PhutilArgumentParser::parseWorkflowsFull(array) called at [<phutil>/src/parser/argument/PhutilArgumentParser.php:333]
  #28 PhutilArgumentParser::parseWorkflows(array) called at [<phabricator>/scripts/sql/manage_storage.php:249]
```

Is the pertinent error the exception about "No configured storage engine" at the top? I have tried to fix this and it seems that some of the SQL changes applied if I check with "storage status". Any ideas? Internet searches haven't provided any similar problems or resolutions.

Comment: Seems that the problem here was that I did not have config files section correct.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the problem here was that I did not have config files section correct. Once I added a local folder location in the configuration I was able to finish the storage upgrade. Now I need to figure out why that storage was not available during upgrade...